# Always fully open documents

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way so that when going to a document always opens it fully instead of being a "ghost" or whatever it's called which goes away if I switch to another file.. This is pretty annoying when checking code between files and find they're gone. I guess in some cases it makes sense, a way to control in which cases it happens would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the setting, disabling this changes it to a more desired behaviour [image]